# Express routing returns 404 despite route being declared

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, routes

So on my backend server, I have declared a route that accepts params

This is the route:

```
router.route('/freeze-check/:region').get(freezeCheck);
```

freezeCheck is just a controller that pulls from the db that filters out products with the regionId.

On my front end I called this route by doing this:

```
const adminRegion = props.authData.admin.region.id;
    const res = await apiCaller.get(`/products/freeze-check`, { params: { region: adminRegion }
```

apiCaller is just axios exported with some settings. I console logged adminRegion multiple times and it returns the expected value, this is a state pulled from redux store however the backend returns with this:

```
GET /api/products/freeze-check?region=1 404 30.114 ms - 164
```

Which I don't get since I declared that route in the backend all the base URLS are working fine I can verify this, am I missing a syntax or something? is this because of the old express or axios version?

I'm using:

express: ^4.14.0

axios: ^0.16.2

Comment: Have u tried to url encode `adminRegion` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your request response,you're not sending the region as params instead as a query.

```
GET /api/products/freeze-check?region=1
```

Try to send the param like this

```
await apiCaller.get(`/products/freeze-check/${adminRegion}`)
```

if the params is optional you could to something like this. pass an trailing question mark in a route

```
router.route('/freeze-check/:region?').get(freezeCheck);
```

the remaining code should be as it should be.

Comment: I tried this but the problem is adminRegion is nullable so that's why I didn't use this solution

Comment: why do you mean by nullable care to elaborate?

Comment: adminRegion is pulled from User details from redux store, not all users have a region

Comment: @Jam have made few changes let me know if this fix this issue

Comment: I tried this and it actually worked, thank you so much